# omit certain records in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table(records) like the following.

```
ID           Status
AA124         Pass
AA125         Pass
Z_AA134       Fail
Z_AA135       Pass
P4235         Fail
```

I want to hide all the records that start with Z_ but not hide the records that start with Z_ and have status as Fail and display others.

Therefore I want to select

```
ID           Status
AA124         Pass
AA125         Pass
Z_AA134       Fail
P4235         Fail
```

from the above table.

My select query only produces Z_ but not others (obviously)

```
Select * from table where ID like 'Z_%' and status = 'Fail'
```

Comment: Show the query you have to start with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   ID not like 'Z|_%' escape '|' or Status = 'Fail'
```

[Working example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cef24/1/0)

Comment: Can u explain whats 'Z|_%' escape '|'

Comment: `_` is a wildcard in a like expression, it means any one character.  So `Z_%` matches `Z_1` as well as `Z11`.  You can use [an escape character](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) to make the `_` mean `_` instead of any character.

Comment: the '%' represents any number of characters in the string that follows a LIKE. The '_' usually represents one character, so if you want a literal underscore, it has to be escaped. '\' is the usual escape character, but he's changing it to a '|'

Comment: Thanks .. This works.. why did u change the escape to '|'.. Is there any advantage of it?

Comment: The reason I use `|` instead of \ is that \ is an escape in many client side languages.  So you require an escape in PHP as well as SQL.  Not a big deal tho

Answer (score 2):

You don't always need to use like, so I want to offer:

```
select *
from t
where status = 'Fail' or left(id, 2) <> 'Z_'
```